# Java7/Tomcat7 64Bit - Strings not renderend in JSP pages

Tags: java, 64-bit, tomcat7

We are running a web application on a windows system with Java7 and Tomcat7 64Bit versions.
After logging in into the webapp and clicking for 2-3 times on any link, all dynamic string content which should be written by the JSPWriter#print method is not rendered anymore in the jsp pages. Numbers (int) are still rendered.

When using Java6 and Tomcat6 there is no problem at all. Using the 32Bit versions is no problem too.
Currently the only way to avoid this error, is to add the debug parameters `-Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n` for tomcat in the registry when running as a service or pass it when deploying from eclipse.

We cannot find any misconfiguration. Any suggestion?

**Edit:** Changing the loglevel from INFO to FINE in tomcat logging.properties also solves the problem. Changing back to INFO and restarting tomcat immidiatly leads to occurence of the problem again.

Comment: Was you application compiled in a 64 bit JDK? If not please try that and update here.

Comment: perhaps its a bug in the java7/tomcat7 interoperability? i would use java 1.6 to try to reproduce the behavior. futhermore you should take a look at the consistency of your string data.. maybe you can try to use a hard coded string to test it again. i am not really feel certain.. but maybe the debug options slow down your code/application so that the string is defined till releasetime?? whatever.. without any code it´s a guessing game..

Comment: There is no problem when using Java6 or even Java7 in a 32Bit version.
HArd coded strings are rendered without any problem. Its just dynamic data read from java objects like `<div class="second_column"><%=ViewUtils.encodeAsHTMLEntities(tValues.getHostName())%>`, where #getHostName() just returns a String and #encodeAsHTMLEntities replaces chars with the HTMP specific encoding, replaces linkebreaks with br tags and inserts invisible linebreaks after each (configured) number of chars. All methods are workling for years with Tomcat5/6 and Java4/5/6. No errors in any logfile as well.

Comment: Another strange one to mention:
We use enums for our database column names.
`public enum ORGANISATIONAL_UNIT implements IColumnDefinition, IArchiveable
{
  ID,
  PARENT_ORG_UNIT_ID,
  ORGANISATIONAL_UNIT_NAME,
  ORGANISATIONAL_UNIT_KEY,....`
and the enum.toString() method returned NULL as well now which in my opion should never ever happen?!?!

Answer (score 0):

The question is not fully answered, but the problem could be narrowed down to a specific behaviour of Java7 64 Bit which I describe in a new question:

[If clause evaluated wrong in Java7_25 64Bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19380736/if-clause-evaluated-wrong-in-java7-25-64bit)