# If clause evaluated wrong in Java7_25 64Bit

Tags: 64-bit, java-7

I have two methods, one to check a given value for being NULL, the string "NULL" or an empty string. The other one to replace html specific chars by there html encoded values and insert spaces to enable linebreaks etc. (See code below). The second method uses the first one to check given value before doing any work.

```
public static String checkForNull(String aString, String aReturnValue)
{
  String tBack = aString;

  if ((aString == null) || (aString.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) || (aString.trim().equals("")))
  {
    tBack = aReturnValue;
  }

  return tBack;
}

public static String encodeAsHTMLEntities(String aValue, boolean aLineBreakAsBR,    String[] aUnencodedParts,
boolean aInsertRatedSpace, int aMinimalWordSize)
{
  StringBuilder tResult = new StringBuilder();

  if(StringUtils.checkForNull(aValue, null) != null)
  {
  String tTempValue = aValue;

  List<String> tUnencodedPartList = new ArrayList<String>();
  if(aUnencodedParts != null)
  {
    tUnencodedPartList.addAll(Arrays.asList(aUnencodedParts));
  }

  /* Replace all linebreaks by HTML-tag if needed. */
  if (aLineBreakAsBR == true)
  {
    tTempValue = tTempValue.replaceAll("\n", "<br />");
    /* Add the br tag to the array containing parts that must not be encoded. */
    tUnencodedPartList.add("<[Bb][Rr]\\s*[/]?>");
  }

  /* HTML-encode the value. */
  int tCharsAfterLastSplitSymbol = 1;
  Pattern tPattern = Pattern.compile("[\\s\\-,.;:]");
  String tSplitterInvisible = "&#8203;";
  String tSplitterVisible = "&#173;";

  if (aMinimalWordSize < 1)
  {
    aMinimalWordSize = Constants.MINIMAL_WORD_SIZE_BEFORE_SEPARATING;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < tTempValue.length(); i++)
  {
    /* Test if we have an exception for the following value. */
    boolean tIsAllowed = false;
    String tStringToCheck = tTempValue.substring(i);
    for (int t = 0; t < tUnencodedPartList.size() && tIsAllowed == false; t++)
    {
      String tUnencodedPart = tUnencodedPartList.get(t);
      String tMatchingString = tStringToCheck.substring(0, tStringToCheck.length() - tStringToCheck.replaceFirst("^(" + tUnencodedPart + ")", "").length());
      if (tMatchingString.length() > 0)
      {
        if (aInsertRatedSpace == true)
        {
          tResult.append(tSplitterInvisible);
        }
        tIsAllowed = true;
        i += tMatchingString.length() - 1;
        tResult.append(tMatchingString);
        if (aInsertRatedSpace == true)
        {
          tResult.append(tSplitterInvisible);
        }
      }
    }
    if (tIsAllowed == false)
    {
      char tChar = tTempValue.charAt(i);

      /* Add the encoded char */
      tResult.append(encodeAsHTMLEntity(tChar));

      /* Add splitter */
      if (aInsertRatedSpace == true)
      {
        /* Check the character for beeing one of our split symbols */
        Matcher tMatcher = tPattern.matcher(Character.toString(tChar));

        String tSplitter = "";

        if (tCharsAfterLastSplitSymbol >= aMinimalWordSize)
        {
          boolean tUseVisibleSplitter = true;

          if (tMatcher.find())
          {
            tUseVisibleSplitter = false;
          }
          else
          {
            /* Check if next character matches to our reg exp */
            if (tTempValue.length() >= (i + 2))
            {
              tChar = tTempValue.charAt(i+1);
              tMatcher = tPattern.matcher(Character.toString(tChar));

              if (tMatcher.find())
              {
                tUseVisibleSplitter = false;
              }
            }

            /* Check if the next characters matches to one of our unencoded parts */
            if (tUseVisibleSplitter)
            {
              String tNextStringToCheck = tTempValue.substring(i+1);
              for (int t = 0; t < tUnencodedPartList.size() && tUseVisibleSplitter == true; t++)
              {
                String tUnencodedPart = tUnencodedPartList.get(t);
                String tMatchingString = tNextStringToCheck.substring(0, tNextStringToCheck.length() - tNextStringToCheck.replaceFirst("^(" + tUnencodedPart + ")", "").length());
                if (tMatchingString.length() > 0)
                {
                  tUseVisibleSplitter = false;
                }
              }
            }
          }

          /* Choose the correct splitting symbol */
          if (tUseVisibleSplitter)
          {
            tSplitter = tSplitterVisible;
          }
          else
          {
            tSplitter = tSplitterInvisible;
          }

          tCharsAfterLastSplitSymbol = 1;
        }
        else
        {
          if (tMatcher.find())
          {
            tSplitter = tSplitterInvisible;

            tCharsAfterLastSplitSymbol = 1;
          }
          else
          {
            tCharsAfterLastSplitSymbol++;
          }
        }

        tResult.append(tSplitter);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      tCharsAfterLastSplitSymbol = 1;
    }
  }
}

return tResult.toString();
}
```

The `checkForNull()` method always returns the correct value when I add a `System.out.println()` to check its return. In method `encodeAsHTMLEntities()` the call to the `checkForNull()` method suddenly stopps working and the `if(StringUtils.checkForNull(aValue, null) != null)` is not entered anymore. I can put the result of `StringUtils.checkForNull(aValue, null)` in another variable and print this one and the returned value is always correct. If I use the `If` to check this variable for being not null the code fails too.

I have discovered two ways to make the code work.
First one is to write the `checkForNull()` like this:

```
public static String checkForNull(String aString, String aReturnValue)
{
  String tBack = aString;
  if (aString == null)
  {
    tBack = aReturnValue;
  }
  else if (aString.equalsIgnoreCase("null")
  {
    tBack = aReturnValue;
  }
  els if (aString.trim().equals(""))
  {
    tBack = aReturnValue;
  }

  return tBack;
}
```

The second one is to run the code in debug mode, which means adding debug parameters to vm or adding any debug statements to the code. (This is the reason for using `System.out.println()`, because any attempt to debug solves the problem so the debugger really is no help in this case)

The code runs fine in an application for years and it is no problem when compiled and running with Java6 32Bit, Java6 64Bit and Java7 32Bit. The error only occurs when compiled and running with Java7 64Bit versions (-> Tested several patches from 7_5 to 7_40)

**Does anyone have an idea what might by the problem here?**
I can provide a main class containing all the code and some files with test strings to reproduce the error if anyone is interested.

**EDIT:** Further tests have shown the error does occur only on windows systems. There is no problem on linux.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. It was a bug in Java which seems to be solved with Java7 Update45